Удаление пробелов между цифрами на картинке Node.js

Есть такая картинка как на ней убрать такие мелкие пропуски есть идеи? node.js
Хотелось бы решить эту проблему быстро

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
